# block specific system calls

Tags: c, operating-system

im working on a problem in C & Linux(Ubuntu) and one of the requirements of the exercise is to block specific system calls, one of them being read(2).

I know I can block signals, but can I treat a system call as a signal and add it to the block list? For example, in unistd.h read(2) is some number, 63 maybe, can I use that id to add it to the block set using functions defined in signals.h? Ive never heard of someone blocking system calls and havent been able to find any useful info so im kind of guessing around here, help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Didn't the class teach what you need to know to accomplish this? Overriding functions is typically done using `LD_PRELOAD`.

Comment: From what context are you to block system calls? No, you absolutely cannot just treat them as a signal, that makes zero sense. Are you a kernel module? Are you a debugger process? Either your teacher is a total dick, you missed some major pre-requisite courses, or you didn't pay nearly enough attention in class.

Comment: What level of blocking are you expected to provide?  Stop an assembler-level trap to the O/S that requests `read` functionality?  Replace the `read` function call with your own?  What should the 'block' do?  Crash the program?

Comment: How exactly is that requirement worded?

Comment: This is not for a class, this is a job screening question, the question is stated as "Write a simple program to allow the reading of a file asynchronously in C or C++ using pthreads and blocking IO system calls (read(2), open(2) and close(2))."

Comment: With that wording, I think it means to use "blocking system calls" (which suspend execution of the caller while they complete), not to prevent access to those calls.  Basically they want you to do blocking IO in a separate thread to do asynchronous IO.

Comment: Wow, that makes sense now!!! So they just want me to do a multithreaded program using read(2), open(2), and close(2) which are blocking io calls!!

Comment: ...with the blocking calls handled by other threads, so the main one can continue while the reading/writing occurs.